# PHP using another sites login?

Tags: php, authentication, registration, minecraft

I am creating a login system for a server I'm starting for the popular game Minecraft. When I was creating the registration system, I realized that someone could pretend to own the in game account when they didn't. One way to solve this would be to force them to go in game and confirm it, but I thought of a simpler idea: Using Minecraft.net authentication.

I see this site doing it: http://optifine.net/capeChange.php

But I have absolutely no idea how to log into their Minecraft using the forum they provide, and then also getting the login response.

Answer (score 0):

See source html code & you'll find there much information about this)

Example:
`https://login.minecraft.net/?user=" + loginNameUrl + "&password=" + passwordUrl + "&version=13`
So use JS, to execute query like this.

Maybe u should copy some JS from that site... :p

Comment: Hmm... thanks, I'll try tinkering with their code, but I don't really understand JavaScript what so ever.